Excel: Dynamic Hyperlink to Other Worksheets
I have a desktop excel workbook that is autosaved to OneDrive with several tabs in the workbook. I want a dynamic HYPERLINK() function to open the link to another worksheet in the same workbook without opening the link in a browser. I can do this using this formula:
=HYPERLINK("#" & A3 & "!A1",A3)

...where A3="SheetName"
However, when I embed this formula in an IF() statement (example below), the hyperlink opens the document in the browser.
=IF(A3="SheetName",
     HYPERLINK("#" & A3 & "!A1",A3),
     A3
   )

...where A3 can be "SheetName" or "Dynamic Info Text"
My only workaround is to embed the IF statement inside of the HYPERLINK function...
=HYPERLINK(
      IF(A3="SheetName",
           "#" & A3 & "!A1",                 <<<links to cell in "SheetName" worksheet
           "#" & ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN())     <<<links to own cell
      )
 A3)
           

However, this workaround creates a link in every cell instead of dynamically creating a link depending on what the contents in A3 are.
Keep in mind, I want this link to keep the user in the same desktop workbook, not open it in a browser.

Hi Jason, which version of Excel are you using? The IF(A3=... formula works fine in Excel Microsoft 365 on my Mac. BTW, to accommodate spaces in sheet names, you may want to add single quotes: =IF(A3 = "Sheet 2", HYPERLINK("#'" & A3 & "'!A1", A3), A3)

I am using Microsoft 365 on Windows 11. I appreciate the tip about spaces. I generally don't use them on sheet names.

Ah, yes. Under Windows it does not display the link with proper formatting (color & underline); but it works as link, so when I click on it take me to the linked cell in the sheet specified. But it does not open in a browser. So I'm not sure what's going on. It the formula is different from what you posted, could you please post the one that opens in browser?

This is the actual formula I am currently using (embedded in a hyperlink) that works. =HYPERLINK(IF(ISERROR(MID(AF4,SEARCH("_",AF4),1)="_"),"#"&ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()),"#"&LEFT(AF4,SEARCH("_",AF4)-1)&".2!A1"),IF(AF4>0,AF4,""))

It only works to make every cell a hyperlink though. The computer I used is not available at the moment so I will have to respond tomorrow with the other IF() formula with a hyperlink embedded in it.

I just tried =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("_", AF4)), HYPERLINK("#" & LEFT(AF4, SEARCH("_", AF4) - 1) & ".2!A1", AF4), AF4 & "") and it works as expected (without opening in browser) under Excel for MS 365 Windows. I'm not sure what's going on.

I was finally able to get back on this computer after a hiatus. I really wonder what is going on now because... here is the code =IF(ISERROR(MID(AF4,SEARCH("_",AF4),1)="_"),           IF(AF4>0,AF4,""),           HYPERLINK("#"&LEFT(AF4,SEARCH("_",AF4)-1)&".2!A1",IF(AF4>0,AF4,""))) and it now works to open the "FALSE" side of the IF() statement while staying in the desktop application, but now it acts like it is a clickable link on the "TRUE" side, and when I click on it, it just opens OneDrive homepage. Seems like a glitch in Excel that needs to be patched.

You may want to double check that the links are correctly formatted with single quotes and brackets as in 'https://onedrive/[file.xls]Sheet1'!A1. Work with links in Excel - Microsoft Support
